# php subtract seconds from 20 minutes

Tags: php, time

I have a base time starting at 20 minutes

00:20:00

i am wanting to subtract 800 seconds from this time 
i have been trying to use the strtotime('-800 seconds') but this dies not seem to be working.

Is there any other easier way to achieve this?

Comment: What does `00:20:00` belong to? In other words, what are you trying to build?

Comment: Its just going to be a simple text based racing game, basicly the base time is 20 minutes to do 5 laps.. the better the car the more seconds you will subtract.

Comment: Ah, I see. The answer below will work well then!

Answer (score 3):

Another option is to use [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) and [DateInterval](http://php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.construct.php).

Create a `DateTime` object, add 20 minutes to it and subtract 800 seconds from it using a `DateInterval`.
Then get the difference between this altered `DateTime` object and a new `DateTime` object.

This will give you a `DateInterval` which has a [format](http://php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.format.php) method to format the interval.

For example:

```
$dateTime = new DateTime();
echo $dateTime
    ->add(new DateInterval('PT20M'))
    ->sub(new DateInterval('PT800S'))
    ->diff(new DateTime())->format("%I:%S");
```

Will result in:

> 06:40

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/FdcdA)

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
$time = "00:20:00";
$unixdatetime = strtotime($time) - 800;
echo strftime("%M:%S",$unixdatetime);  // 06:40
```

Comment: Perhaps removing the `%I` from `strftime()` would be better for the result? Since they're looking for minutes and lower? Either way, nice solution :)